# Entity to XML (EF5.0)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm building and XML file representing and Entity. After many hours this seems to be working, but is there a better way ?

```
var entityContents   =  (from p in context.people select p).ToListAsEnumerable();
var XmlString = CollectMemebersNameValue("people" , entityContents);

public static string CollectMemebersNameValue( string entityName,  IEnumerable entityQuery)
    {
        var xmlText = new StringBuilder();
        xmlText.AppendLine("<" + entityName + ">");
        foreach (var item in entityQuery)
        {
            xmlText.AppendLine("<Row>"); 
            foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if ( ! prop.PropertyType.Name.Contains("ICollection"))
                {
                    var nname = prop.Name;
                    var nvalue = prop.GetValue(item, null);
                    xmlText.AppendLine("<" + nname +  ">" + nvalue + "</" + nname + ">");
                }

            }
        }
        xmlText.AppendLine("</" + entityName + ">");
        return xmlText.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Use an XML serializer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), e.g.

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourObjectType));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
xs.Serialize(ms, yourActualObject);
string sampleXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

Whether you're serializing your entity or a view of your entity, it works the same way.  Just ensure whatever object you are serializing *is* serializable.

Comment: Be aware that deserialising and reattaching the entity will bypass firing the ObjectMaterialized event of the ObjectContext. You'll also get issues with proxy objects if you have them enabled.